# Android: How to set the TextView to a getter method using textview.setText(getter)

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I have a getter and setter class that stores names and nicknames.

I store the text entered into the EditText field into a string and set my setter method to that string in one Activity.

```
Person personInfo = new Person();
 String storeName = text.getText().toString();
        personInfo.setName(storeName);
```

This is put into the onCreate method of one activity.

Then in another activity, I want to get the name from the setter, but it keeps returning null.

```
TextView name;
Person personInfo;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                name.setText(personInfo.getName()); 
}
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you need to access something from one activity to another, you either pass that item using intent or store it in the `persistent` storage and access it later..

Answer (score 0):

```
Person personInfo;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText(personInfo.getName()); 
}
```

Line 1 of this snippet declares `personInfo`, and you never initialize anything in it.  You need to come other with a way of sending `personInfo` from Activity 1 to Activity 2 using intents.  (You'll have to create a new `Person` object and initialize it from the data sent in the intents unless you want to set `Person` up with the `singleton` class model.)

Comment: Does that mean I can't use getter and setters? I'm just trying to find a way to use getters and setters for the information.

Comment: You can use getters and setters.  In Activity 1, use the `getter` to get the information out of the object and put it in an intent and pass that.  In Activity 2, either set the text view straight from the information in the intent, or use the information in the intent to instantiate another object of that class.

Comment: The only alternative is to use the Singleton class model, but passing information with intents is probably much better in most cases.

Comment: So then I use get first instead of using set? Don't I set it first?

Comment: Yes, but once you have set it, you get it so you can pass it with the intent.

Comment: I have made the following edits above, but I don't know if that is correct. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass the personInfo object from  activity one to second using intents and then try to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getter and setter,here is a good method.

```
PersonFactory factory;
Person person;

public PersonFactory getInstance(){
    if(factory == null){
        factory = new PersonFactory();
    }
    return factory;
}

public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}
```

You can set the value in Activity1

```
Person personInfo = new Person();
String storeName = text.getText().toString();
personInfo.setName(storeName);
PersonFactory.getInstance().setPerson(personInfo);
```

and get the value in Activity2 like this.

```
TextView name;
Person personInfo;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(PersonFactory.getInstance().getPerson().getName()); 
}
```